# Why is Open Containing Folder disabled in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Open Containing Folder in VS 2022 seems to be weirding out. This is in the Solution Explorer, right-clicking a .cs file. The file definitely exists, and the [Open Folder Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidRoller.OpenFolderExtension2022) *does* work (and also adds the second `Open Containing Folder` to the menu), but the built-in open folder function doesn't work.

I've not experienced this before. Is this something I've broken with a setting somewhere? Is there any way to fix this?

[image]